# UIBezierPath drawing issues

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I created a class called myBezierPaths, with two member variables of type UIBezierPath and UIColor, and then I tried to use object of this class to draw the bezierpath, but I am not getting bezierpath, below is my code

```
//Bezierpath.h

@interface BezierPath : NSObject
{
UIBezierPath *m_bezierPath;
UIColor *m_pathColor;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIBezierPath *bezierPath;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *pathColor;
@end


//drawingView.m


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{ 
for (BezierPath *pathobj in m_pathArray) 
{ 
[pathobj.pathColor setStroke];
[pathobj.pathColor setFill];
[pathobj.bezierPath strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0]; 
} 
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
*self.myPath = [[BezierPath alloc] init];*

myPath.bezierPath.lineWidth = 5; 
myPath.bezierPath.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;
myPath.bezierPath.flatness = 0.0;
myPath.bezierPath.lineJoinStyle = kCGLineJoinRound;
myPath.bezierPath.miterLimit = 200.0;

self.myPath.pathColor = [UIColor redColor];

UITouch *mytouch=[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0]; 

[myPath.bezierPath moveToPoint:[mytouch locationInView:self]];
[m_pathArray addObject:self.myPath];
}



- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    UITouch *mytouch=[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
    [self.myPath.bezierpath addLineToPoint:[mytouch locationInView:self]];    

    [self setNeedsDisplay];    
}
```

hope I am clear with my explanation, waiting for reply

Regards
Ranjit

Comment: [self setNeedsDisplay]; ,try this..

Comment: hey thanks for reply, but it wont work

Comment: Remember I before E in bezierpath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in your `drawRect` you don't actually fill the shape.  You do stroke it (basically draw a border) but you need to call `[pathObj.bezierPath fill];` to actually fill the shape with a color.

There's a lot of code you're not showing, so it's hard to tell where the problem might be.  I would create a breakpoint in the `drawRect` method to determine if all of the variables are there.  For example, you show (what I assume) to be an array: `m_pathArray`.  Are you sure it's initialized?  Are you sure the properties of `BezierPath` are working correctly?  I notice that on `touchesBegan` you set the `pathColor` but only access/read the `bezierPath` variable.  Has that been initialized?  Where do you create the 'm_bezierPath' instance variable?  Do you create it in the BezierPath `init` method or lazily instantiate it on access?

So those are a few things you could check.

Comment: hey thanks for your reply, m_bezierPath instance variable is initialized in init of UIBezeirPath and m_pathArray is also initialized and mypath is an object of type BezeirPath(custom Class)

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint in drawRect and check the variables?  A helpful tip: You can check variables in the console by typing: `po variable_name`. You can even make method calls, so to check that pathobj is returning a proper UIBezierPath you can type: `po [pathobj bezierPath]` when in the loop to check that it's returning a proper UIBezierPath.

Comment: hey Aaron my issue is solved I had not initialized members of my customClass BezierPath in custom array. Now I want to know how can I set diffrent colors for my bezierPath?

Comment: Calling `setFill` or `setStroke` on a `UIColor` instance before you call `fill` or `stroke` on a UIBezierPath should set the fill/stroke color.  If it doesn't, check again that your pathobj is returning a valid UIColor object.

Comment: hey thanks Aaron, that issue is solved, I want to implement the eraser  as typical real word eraser, which erasers only specific part which is rubbed, how can I implement that any suggestions.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know.  Erasing whole paths is easy.  But erasing part of a path....that's a lot more difficult.  You'll probably have to do a lot of searching to find some answers.  Unfortunately, I've never tried to implement something like that so I don't have an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show your `touchesMoved` event handler , but i would expect something like this. Otherwise all you are doing is creating a set of paths of length zero.

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

UITouch *mytouch=[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0]; 

[self.myPath.bezeirPath lineToPoint:[mytouch locationInView:self]];


}
```

Comment: hey warren, thanks for reply, I have added my touchesMoved event handler, and its same as what you have written, but I am not understanding, where I am going wrong. previously I was using an object of UIBezeirpath and it was working, as soon as I made a class, its not working

Answer (score 0):

@Ranjit need some help I've same problem ...
I want to change the colors of UIbezierpath.
but wen i select the color my previous path also automatically gets colored with new color.

In My first Image i draw a line and selected color is red.
but when i select yellow color to draw another line the previous line also change to yellow color.(image no 2)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi umesh, if you are using bezeirPath to draw, create a class consisting of two member variables 1) UIBezeirPath and second is UIColor, and initiliase it properly, then check out the above code, u will be good to go